# What is the meaning of "within next two days"?

Tags: vocabulary

Is it, within today and tomorrow 
or 
within tomorrow and day after?

Comment: Should be _within **the** next two days_.

Comment: It's a wishy-washy statement that could have either of the two meanings you provide. There is a fuzzy period during the middle of the day during which the meaning slides from one to the other, further complicated by other factors such as business closing times and so on. If you're after precision you could say 'within the next 48 hours', which is more explicit about the deadline, or something like 'before close of business Wednesday'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression ***within the next two days*** does not have a precise meaning, and would have to be understood in context.

If someone were to use that expression during , say, late afternoon, then they probably mean *by the end of the day after tomorrow*.

But if they were to use the same expression first thing in the morning, they might mean *by the end of tomorrow*. On the other hand, if they meant *by the end of tomorrow*, then they are more likely to have actually said that.

You may also hear a variation of this expression, such as *within two working days*, which (depending on the industry and other context) may exclude Saturday and Sunday. Hence, if *within two working days* were said on a Thursday, it would probably mean *before the end of Monday*.

In conclusion, the expression ***within the next two days*** does not have an exact meaning, but most commonly means *before the end of the day after tomorrow*. If in doubt, check with the person who said it.